# sam local invoke, will it actually upload to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I've made tons of search but couldn't find an answer. I got this lambda function which basically uploads file to s3 and I got a test s3 bucket. I run the function via `sam local invoke...` everything seems to be working fine no error messages nothing but I dont see this file on s3 bucket. When running the function locally it actually doesn't upload it to s3? I would be happy if you confirm this.
Thanks.

Comment: Using the same credentials that the lambda  can you upload the file to s3 with the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a function puts an object into an S3 bucket, it will do you it, when it is triggered by "sam local invoke".

I would suggest checking the credentials, bucket names/paths, waiting for the response from the PutObject event